# Assigning "HTML Select Control" Values in PageLoad() Event

Tags: c#, javascript, html, post, postback

I want to Use only the HTML Controls on my page. For that i want to use some text boxes and a HTML select(List box) and a Submit button for Post Event.
The Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function dropdown(mySel) {
        var myWin, myVal;
        myVal = mySel.options[mySel.selectedIndex].value;
        if (myVal) {
            if (mySel.form.target) myWin = parent[mySel.form.target];
            else myWin = window;
            if (!myWin) return true;
            myWin.location = myVal;
        }
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

This Java Script i am using for the HTML Select List.
The Rest of the Code are As follows:

```
<form action="feedback.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return dropdown(this.feeds)">
<h1>
    Let us know your inconvenience for the following Listing:
</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Type : </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>ID : </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Title: </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            User ID:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtUserid" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contact:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtContact" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtemail" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <b>Please Select the given option </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <select name="feeds">
                <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
                <option value="">Option1</option>
                <option value="">Option2</option>
                <option value="">Option3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <b>Write your Comment Here: </b>
            <br />
            <textarea id="TextArea" name="txtcomment" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <Efextra:Captcha ID="Captcha1" runat="server" TabIndex="29" ValidationErrorMessage="Verification Code"
        ValidationGroup="Feeds" ValidationText="*"></Efextra:Captcha>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit FeedBack" validationgroup="Feeds" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have a XML document having the following Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feedback>
<Options>
  <ID>0</ID>
  <option>[Select your option]</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <option>I got Incomplete/wrong information posted here.</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <option>The Content is not in Proper Format.</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <option>How can get the similar type of properties?</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <option>This Listing is Sold and Still Displaying here.</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>5</ID>
  <option>I can not send SMS for this Listing.</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>6</ID>
  <option>I can not get the Contact Information of the owner of this post.</option>
 </Options>
 <Options>
  <ID>7</ID>
  <option>My problem is not given here!</option>
 </Options>
</Feedback>
```

Now what i ahve to do is:
When Page load it checks whether the user is registered or not, if he/She is a registered user, the first four field [User ID, Name, Contact, Email] can be be loaded itself.
for this my code behind file assigns value like this:

```
User FeedUser = Propertywala.User.GetAuthUser();
Txt1.Text=Feeduser.UserID; and so on..
```

If he/she is not a registered user then User will get this field blank and i will get fetch all the filled values through Page.Request().

Second Issue is that i want to load the Option of select box from XML file which is above.
I am a newbie to this code and flow. so please anybody can help me doing this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did it without using a single asp control. I solved the problem like this:

```
<form name="feedback" action="FeedBack.aspx">
<h1>
    Let us know your inconvenience for the following Listing:
</h1>
<table>
    <%if (IsUserLoggedIn) %>
    <%{ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>User ID:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<%=VisitingUser.UserIdn%>" size="30" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<%=VisitingUser.FullName%>" size="30" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Contact:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<%=VisitingUser.MobileNumber %>" size="30" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Email:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<%=VisitingUser.PrimaryEmail%>" size="30" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
    <%else%>
    <%{ %><tr>
        <td>
            <h3>
                Enter the Folowing details to submit the Feedback:
            </h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contact:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtContact" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="txtEmail" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
<br />
<%if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["property"], out Property)) %>
<%{ %>
<%Propertywala.Property prp = new Propertywala.Property(Property);%>
<%if (prp.OwnerId > 0) %>
<%{ %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Property ID :</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Property.ToString() %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Property Title :</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=prp.AutoGeneratedTitle %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%} %>
<%} %>
<%else if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["project"], out Project)) %>
<%{ %>
<%Propertywala.Project prj = new Propertywala.Project(Project);%>
<%if (prj.UserId > 0) %>
<%{ %><table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Project ID : </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Project.ToString() %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Project Title : </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=prj.Title %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%} %>
<%} %>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <b>Please Select the given option </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <select name="feeds">
                <%foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xNode in FeedXmlList)%>
                <%{ %>
                <option value="<%=xNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText%>">
                    <%=xNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText%></option>
                <%} %>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 400px">
            <b>Write your Comment Here: </b>
            <br />
            <textarea name="txtcomment" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <Efextra:Captcha ID="Captcha1" runat="server" TabIndex="29" ValidationErrorMessage="Verification Code"
        ValidationGroup="Feeds" ValidationText="*"></Efextra:Captcha>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit FeedBack" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And finally in Code behind file i just put some required condition and fetch all the html values through request.form, like this:

```
if (Request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post" && Request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["feeds"]) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["txtcomment"]))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["property"]) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["project"]))
            {
                if (IsUserLoggedIn||(!IsUserLoggedIn && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["txtName"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["txtContact"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["txtEmail"])))
                {
                    if (Request.Form["feeds"] != "[Select your option]")
                    {
                        Mail(Request.Form["feeds"], Request.Form["txtcomment"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Common.ClientMessage("Select the Option and Retry to Submit the feeds.", CommonConsts.AlertType.info);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Common.ClientMessage("Unregistered user must fill their name and Contact Details!", CommonConsts.AlertType.info);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Anybody has any better idea to optimise this code?
Any comment will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the `runat="server"` attribute to the `input type="text"` controls as well. Then you can access them in codebehind just like a webcontrol. The same goes for your `select` html control.

For the Xml document you're going to need an XmlReader object. For the implementation of that, please look up [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)

Comment: Ok Rest of the things are ok.
I will put the runat="server" attribute in every control.
But can you tell me by giving an example how can i bind my xml data to this select box?

Comment: And what about HTML label? How can i assigns values to it?
<LABEL FOR=user ACCESSKEY=U>User</LABEL>
I want this User mentioned according to logic in code behind file.

Comment: I don't want to use HTML runat="server". It should be complete HTML control. How can i do that?

Comment: Uhm, if you don't want to use runat=server, then the binding of an XML document is certainly beyond me.